# PHP: using $_POST within a loop

Tags: php, post

On one page I have a dynamically created form which has this element in it (note I have left out some stuff for clarity, eg: table and form elements):

```
$getallusers = "SELECT * FROM `ft_users`";
$usersstmt = $modx->query($getallusers);
while ($row = $usersstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         echo "<td><input type='text' name='" . $row['userid'] . "' id='" . $row['userid'] . "' size='4'></td>";
    }
```

On the form processing page I am trying to retrieve the values:

```
$getallusers = "SELECT * FROM `ft_users`";
$usersstmt = $modx->query($getallusers);
while ($rowuser = $usersstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$userpoints = trim($_POST["user_ids"][$rowuser["userid"]]);

}
```

If I do `print_r($_POST);` I get the array of data I sent in the form so I know the forms working OK. Its just the part converting the data into a variable:

```
$userpoints = trim($_POST["user_ids"][$rowuser["userid"]]);
```

Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

Comment: you assign to `rowuser`, and you output `row` in first code

Comment: @JonathandeM. yep your right, sorry that was a transcribing error and not the cause of the issue

Comment: what happens when you echo `$_POST["user_ids"]` ?

Comment: @Andrew hmm i get nothing - not even a NULL

Answer (score 0):

Change this in the first code block:-

```
while ($rowuser = $usersstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

to

```
while ($row = $usersstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: Sorry all, dont down vote - he answered before I fixed my question (spelling mistake I made when writing it out)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your POST retrieval. Exactly `$_POST["user_ids"]`; it should match whatever you have in your `name='" . $row['userid'] . "'`

Browse the page source and look it up